# Package.xml format to retrieve Messaging Templates

Tags: salesforcedx, package.xml

I have a Salesforce Service enabled Sandbox and I have created some messaging templates in Service Setup/Home/Channels/Messaging/Messaging Templates.
I need to retrieve metadata related to those Templates to vs code using sfdx. How can I modify my package.xml to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that it is not supported by Metadata API, I have found a workaround, with Workbench I queried object Messaging Template:

```
SELECT DeveloperName,MasterLabel,Message FROM MessagingTemplate
```

Then in VS Code, exported that result as a JSON file and imported on my other sandbox.

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "<SOQL query>" -d "<exported file path>"

sfdx force:data:tree:import -f "<exported file path>"
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to query for channels associated with messaging templates, e.g. SMS, WhatsApp, Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Add the [MessagingTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_messagingtemplate.htm) object to your package:

```
<types>
  <members>*</members>
  <name>MessagingTemplate</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Im getting this error: ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}type invalid at this location

Comment: @YanetP1988 Whoops, yeah, that should have been `name`, not `type`.

Comment: hahah, no problem. Still, now this: === WARNING: The following metadata isn’t in your org. If it’s not new, someone deleted it from the org.
Entity type: 'MessagingTemplate' is unknown

Comment: @YanetP1988 Interesting. I need to some research on this. It doesn't appear in my dev org.

Comment: I've been doing some research and it seems that it is not supported by Metadata API